# Cannot create a list item with a blue box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a list item which looks like

[image]

Where the colour is on the left, then the rest of it is white.

I don't know where to begin, so after trial and error I've made progress using the CSS selector `::before` but it's not quite there and I'm not sure how to complete this

My code is trivial

```
<ul>
<li>me</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li{
  background-color:#fff;
}

ul li::before{
  content: "\00a0\00a0";
  display:inline;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

The text `me` is right up against the colour too sadly. And it's hacky, having to add a "\00a0" for each white space

https://jsfiddle.net/s8fj6huh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` on `::before` and give the `li` some `padding-left` which should be more then or same as the width of `::before`

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  background-color:#fff;
  padding-left:20px;
  position:relative;
}

ul li::before{
  content: ' ';
  display:inline;
  width:20px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li>me</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: relative` on parent element and `position: absolute` on pseudo-element. You can also add `padding-left` on `li` that is >= then width of pseudo-element.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
ul li::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>me</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use `Flexbox` so you just need to set `display: flex` on `li`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
ul li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>me</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep your pseudos for other things and use padding + gradient.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 45px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFA46F 40px, transparent 40px);
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px
}
ul li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FE62AC 40px, transparent 40px);
}
ul li:nth-child(3n) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E7ED69 40px, transparent 40px);
  background-color: #def
}
ul li:nth-child(4n) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #59CD6A 40px, transparent 40px);
}
ul li:nth-child(5n) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0C96EE 40px, transparent 40px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>You
    <br/>&
    <br/>me</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't feel it's right to unmark an answer, but, I did mark a little too early. This answer is actually what I went with, sorry I can only give 1* +1

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions do not worry, i'm glad i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
ul.a {
list-style-type: circle;
background: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="a"> 
  <li>me</li>
</ul>
```